# Jquery .change and .focusout functions together

Tags: jquery

I need to check if the textboxes and the select option box and then enable the "Submit" button. If the textbox is empty and the select option box is none the "Submit" button should not be enabled. how to do that.

```
$("#textbox1, #textbox2").focusout(function(){
    if($("#textbox1").val()!=""
    && $("#textbox1").val()!=""){
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

This code works fine but I need when the 2 textboxes are not empty and the select option box is not none the submit button should be enabled how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#textbox1, #textbox2, #select1").focusout(function(){
    if($("#textbox1").val()!=""
    && $("#textbox2").val()!="" && $( "#select1 option:selected" ).text()!="none"){
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/As9AR/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-

```
$("#textbox1, #textbox2").focusout(function(){
if($("#textbox1").val()!="" && $("#textbox1").val()!="")
{
   if($('#checkbox:checked')==true)
   $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
}
else
{
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post your html also...

Anyway try this:

```
$("#textbox1, #textbox2, #select").focusout(function () {
    $("#textbox1, #textbox2, #select").each(function () {
        if (this.value != '') {
            $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
});
```